# Run a java webservice on a server

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-services, jdbc

I have a Java Webservice code . Currently I am running it on a localhost. What changes should be made when I run this on another server(with static IP).

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class RetailerWS {
 public String customerData(){
  String customerInfo = "";
  try{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retailer","root","chathura");
  //Find customer information where the customer ID is maximum
  PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE C_ID = (SELECT MAX(C_ID) FROM customers)");
  ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

   while(result.next()){
    customerInfo = customerInfo + result.getString("name") + "&" + result.getString("C_ID") + "&"+result.getString("address") + "&"+result.getString("email");
  //Here "&"s are added to the return string. This is help to split the string in Android application
   }
  }

  catch(Exception exc){
   System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
   }

  return customerInfo;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not to make any change if database is also hosted on the same server. If DB is on other server then change this line :

```
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retailer","root","chathura");
```

to have the ip/address or hostname of your DB server.

Your web service clients need to use the address of you new server where you are hosting the web service, to call its methods.

Comment: OK , please tell how can I deploy this webservice to remote server from my PC. And how can I use this for my android app.. Please help.. am a beginner

Comment: @aav Your webservice must be part of some war file. Take that war file and deploy it on the webserver hosted on your remote server.